# How to set up ThreeJS Scrollable plane in a React project?

Tags: reactjs, graphics, three.js, 2d, react-three-fiber

I'd like to use ThreeJS to create a 2D plane with left, right, top, and bottom edges. The camera should not be able to scroll past these bounds. Why ThreeJS for a scene with just a 2D plane? Because I want to make use of shaders to paint the plane and might eventually add 3D content down the line.

How do I setup such a scene? Does the camera move around the plane? Does the plane move around the camera? How do I enforce the "bounded edges" that the camera can't scroll past?

Finally, do I need to use React-Three-Fiber since it will live in a React app? I've tried setting up the scene with just ThreeJS, but I can't get my Controls to work the way I want and was wondering if I NEED React-Three-Fiber to bridge the gap.

Answer (score 1):

Eventually got it working. Potentially may have been easier with R3F, but I took the ThreeJS approach, as many people seem to think it offers more flexibility. Hope this helps someone in the future:

```
import React, { useEffect, useRef } from "react";
import * as THREE from "three";
import {OrbitControls} from "three/examples/jsm/controls/OrbitControls";

const Window = () => {
    const windowRef = useRef(null);

    const setupScene = () => {
        // renderer
        const renderer = new THREE.WebGLRenderer();
        renderer.setSize( window.innerWidth, window.innerHeight );
        windowRef.current.appendChild( renderer.domElement );

        // scene
        const scene = new THREE.Scene();

        // camera
        const camera = new THREE.PerspectiveCamera( 75, window.innerWidth/window.innerHeight, 0.1, 1000 );
        camera.position.set(0,0,10);
    
        // controls
        const controls = new OrbitControls(camera, renderer.domElement);
        controls.target.set( 0, 0, 0 ); // view direction perpendicular to XY-plane
        controls.enableRotate = false;
        controls.enablePan = true;
        controls.mouseButtons = { LEFT: THREE.MOUSE.PAN };
        controls.minDistance = 1;
        controls.maxDistance = 100;

        const geometry = new THREE.PlaneBufferGeometry(100, 100, 10, 10);
        const material = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial( { color: 0x00ff00 } );
        const plane = new THREE.Mesh( geometry, material );
    
        scene.add( plane );
    
        const animate = function () {
            controls.update();
            requestAnimationFrame( animate );
            renderer.render( scene, camera );
        };
    
        animate();

        return () => windowRef.current.removeChild( renderer.domElement);
    };

    useEffect(setupScene);

    return (
        <div ref={windowRef} />
    );
}

export default Window;
```